# How to detect first element (destination) when mouse out from the origin element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I detect the class of  First Element(Destination) When Mouse Out From The Origin Element `.E`?

```js
$(".E").mouseout(function() {});
```

```css
body { padding: 20px;}
#box { width: 170px; height: 300px;}
#box-1,#box-2,#box-3,#box-4,#box-5,#box-6,#box-7,#box-8,#box-9 { height: 50px; width: 50px;  border: 1px solid #ccc;  float: left;}
#box-5 {background: khaki;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <div id="box-1" class="A"></div>
  <div id="box-2" class="B"></div>
  <div id="box-3" class="C"></div>
  <div id="box-4" class="D"></div>
  <div id="box-5" class="E"></div>
  <div id="box-6" class="F"></div>
  <div id="box-7" class="G"></div>
  <div id="box-8" class="H"></div>
  <div id="box-9" class="I"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let leftE = false;

$(".E").mouseout(() => leftE = true);

$(window).mouseover(function(event) {
  if(leftE) {
    const el = event.target // <<<<
    leftE = false;
  }
});
```

Just use a flag to catch the next mouseover event after the mouseleave.

Comment: Thanks Joans but how to detect which element is destination?

Comment: Hello @MonaCoder the element is const el.